# Array to string conversion laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

```
    $data = $request->all();

    if (!empty($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key === "_token")
            {
                continue;
            }

            $val = [
                'questionnaire_id' => $questionnaire_id,
                'question_id' => $key,
                'answer' => $value
            ];

            $answer = Answer::create($val);
        }
    }
```

This is my array

```
    {
"_token": "URP1tlRfoD0RFMYIgVIyBX1AYaobDsQU2wnvxC1r",
"questionnaires_id": "5",
"questions": {
"2": "a",
"10": "3",
"11": "b",
"44": "2018-08-01"
}
}
```

this is my model class

```
class Answer extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'questionnaire_id', 'question_id', 'answer'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: **So whats your question?**

Comment: how can i store data in my database model? and how can solve this error?

Comment: You didn't add what error you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
    $qs = $request->questions;
    $qr = $request->questionnaires_id;
    foreach ($qs as $k => $q)
    {
        $val = [
            'questionnaire_id' => $qr,
            'question_id' => $k,
            'answer' => $q
        ];
        $answer = Answer::create($val);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert only array to string, You should use php function like `json_encode()`

Comment: $datas = json_encode("," ,$data);
try it, but not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

To store array in DB/Model you can do this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'answer' => 'array'
];
```

And `$answer` can be:

```
$answer = array($your_data);
```

Comment: i want to store 1 array data as 1 row in database. And please can u tell details about what you suggest me?

Comment: Well you need to say that in your question. I thought you want to store array in your database as value. And to use it as array on fetch

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this flow.

```
$data = $request->all();

    if (!empty($data))
    {
        $questionnaires_id = 0;
        $questions = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key === "_token")
            {
                continue;
            }

            if($key === "questionnaires_id")
            {
                $questionnaires_id = $value;
            }

            if($key === "questions")
            {
                $questions = $value;
            }
        }

         foreach ($questions as $key => $value) {
            $val = [
                'questionnaire_id' => $questionnaires_id,
                'question_id' => $key,
                'answer' => $value
            ];

            $answer = Answer::create($val);
         }
    }
```

Comment: if your $data is in json string then you first have to convet it in to the PHP array by `$data = json_decode($data);`.